# Срабатывание :hover у родителя в любом месте кроме .особенного-блока

Tags: html, css

Допустим я имею 2 блока с такой структурой

```css
#parent {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #222125;
}

#parent:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#children {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="children">Нужно, наведя сюда, вернуть фон у #parent</div>
</div>
```

И нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на `#parent` менялся его фон, но после того как навёл на `#children` фон возвращался.

Нужно сделать так что бы свойство `:hover у #parent` сработало, когда курсор находится на `#parent` везде, но если курсор находится на `#children` то отменить это свойство.

На JS такое можно сделать, мне интересно возможно ли такое без js.

Спасибо

Comment: Размечтался.....)))

Comment: @Air вы про что?)

Comment: Про то, что без JS не возможно...  Можно схитрить с псевдо-элементами, но при условии, что у родителя один дочерний элемент.... И  не сложная верстка... С данным примером, можно что-то  придумать, но овчинка не стоит выделки... На практике не понадобиться это извращение...

Comment: @Air на самом деле там структура средняя, но в родительском блоке всего 2 элемента

Answer (score 3):

Можно Вот такое извращение реализовать...

```css
#parent {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #222125;
}

#parent:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#children {
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00f;
  color: white;
}

#children:before,
#children:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#children:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}

#children:hover#children:before {
  background-color: #222125;
}

#children:hover#children:after {
  background-color: #222125;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="children">Нужно, наведя сюда, вернуть фон у #parent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но ведь, вероятно, проще через js сделать?)

Comment: Ну при такой банально верстке, да...Но если что сложнее,  это уже настоящее извращением будет, реализовать так...))